# Want to run Specific node or group of nodes and capture the output into a variable in kedro jupyter lab

Tags: kedro

I am new to kedro, I am trying to run Spaceflights tutorial. I want to run the complete data_processing_pipeline 'dp', and capture the output in a dataframe. I am running it on Jupyter Lab. I used the following command:
model_input_table = session.run(pipeline_name='dp')
or
model_input_table = context.run(pipeline_name='dp')

I even tried running a specific node to capture the output returned into a variable.

Nothing seems working! Please help!

Answer (score 0):

So the way to do this is to use the `catalog` object which (should also be in scope) and read the results of the files persisted on disk. So you can do `catalog.load('companies')` and inspect the `DataFrame` right there in your notebook.

You can also do `catalog.list()` to inspect which items in your catalog are available for inspection. Kedro is fundamentally dataset-centric so we always interact with data via the `DataCatalog`, the pipeline is just something that organises the execution order at runtime.

Comment: That doesn't answer. It seems like he wants to capture the result of a node in memory, not the data source. Unless you save on disk the result of a node, which can be pretty annoying, I still don't know how to capture the dataframe in memory